# Will a error.log or access.log of size more 10 GB affect the performance of a RoR application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx, passenger

Will a error.log or access.log of size more 10 GB affect the performance of a RoR application?

Application is running on a Linux server server. NGINX/PASSENGER combo is used for hosting the app.

Server is having a RAM of 4GB.

Comment: nginx's log has nothing to do with RoR (unless you run out of disk space)

Comment: Sorry if my question is confusing... Each time when Ruby web app is accessed something is added to error log or access log. If the log files are too big, will writing on those log files take up too much time/processing effort? I gave additional details like web server details to help

Comment: Not that you'll notice. Anyway, don't forget to use log rotate (or something similar) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. 

But there are various other possibilities which might affect your server's performance like your server's disk and filesystem composition, amount of free disk space you have and amount of disk IO your RoR application requires. 

In any case, rotate your logs weekly or daily depending on your traffic and monitor your RAM and Processor usage.